# How to debug over wifi with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb

I am trying to set up to debug an Android app on a tablet (running 6.0.1) over wifi (not over USB, because the app needs hardware plugged into the USB port).

Gone through the connection process from a Windows command prompt to get adb to talk over wifi, and that seems OK - device is recognised on 192.168.0.16:5555.

I assumed I would then be able to load and debug the app from the Android Studio UI. Wrong - "no devices present". As soon as I plug it in via USB, it shows up.

I think I must be missing a trick here - how can I get Android Studio to load and debug it over wifi?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**File -> Setting -> plugins -> Browse Repositories -> (search) Android wifi ADB**

> Install this plugin in your Android Studio

*if you want to debug your app using wifi then, the first time you have to use an USB cable and see the right side of the panel click on (Android Wifi Adb) tool, and see your device here*

click on "**connect**" button

**NOTE: Ensure that your computer and device are connected to the same WiFi network.**

[image]

**Then display a message "*Device is connected*"
after you are able to debug with wifi**

> **==================== Another Way =====================**

**Step 1)**. Open CMD

**Step 2)**. Navigate to ADB containing folder (platform-tools)

```
   Ex.  C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>
```

**Step 3)**. Write command `adb tcpip 5555` *(Make Sure your device and computer both connected with the same wifi).*

**Step 4)**. Write command `adb connect {Mobile IP Address}:5555`

```
   Ex.  adb connect 192.168.1.1:5555
```

**Great Success**

Comment: Magic! Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: 2021 solution for me on MacOS was Android Studio -> Preferences -> Plugins -> (search Android WiFiADB)

Comment: how to get the {mobile Ip Address}

Comment: In your mobile setting, you will find about phone "scroll down and there you will see an IP Address" @DrDeo

Answer (score 2):

Now it's more easy to run/debug your app with wifi.
In latest Android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1, you will get default feature of wifi debugging.

Follow the steps in android studio

Device manager -> Physical -> Pair using wifi -> You can see one QR code in popup
[image]

Follow the steps in Android mobile (Make sure you need Android 11+ device)

Settings -> Developer options -> wireless debugging -> Pair device with QR code.
[image]

Now just scan the QR code of android studio and your device will be connected for wifi run/debug your app.

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac**

Android Studio Menu -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Search for ADB Wi-Fi

You can find many options there, here is the one I am using & working perfectly for Android 10 & lower.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14969-adb-wi-fi

For Android 11 and above Android Studio Bumblebee provides that within Run options.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm on macOS Ventura, with latest Android Studio and Nokia 7Plus under Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please check android [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless) to debug over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

**To debug over WIFI in Android Studio for Windows follow below steps,**

1. Connect the PC/Laptop and Mobile device in same WIFI network.
2. Connect the mobile device using USB.
3. Download the **platform tools** for Windows from below link and extract it.
   https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools
4. Open the downloaded platform tools folder and open command prompt from there itself.
5. Type the command,
   **adb tcpip 5555**
6. Type the command,
   **adb connect <mobile_ip_address>:5555**
7. Unplug the USB and now debugging can be done.

**NOTE:**

1. Using above steps the WIFI debugging can be done in all Android versions.
2. You can also pair using device using WIFI by clicking **Pair Device Using WIFI** under **Available devices** in android studio. But that works from Android 11+ devices alone. So I recommend above steps to follow.